# Issue rendering UIDatePicker on iPhone XS and 11plus only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I need a combined date & time picker in a Xamarin.Forms project, so I used a custom View & Renderer which works great on my iPhone 8 Plus test device. Unfortunately on an iPhone XS or 11 Pro (physical devices, both on 13.3) the picker does not render correctly - all the dates are greyed out, and time is completely invisible yet present (I can feel the 'clicks' when swiping up/down in the area where it would be). Unsurprisingly, the simulator for both those devices renders correctly. Full sample project along with screenshots from both devices [on GitHub](https://github.com/esenciadev/DatePickerTest). Here's the relevant code from the renderer in case anything jumps out:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyDatePicker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        _datePicker.ValueChanged -= DatePickerOnValueChanged;
    }

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        if (Control == null)
        {
            _datePicker = new UIDatePicker(new CGRect(
                e.NewElement.Bounds.X,
                e.NewElement.Bounds.Y,
                e.NewElement.Bounds.Width,
                e.NewElement.Bounds.Height
             ));
            _datePicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime;
            _datePicker.Date = (NSDate) Element.Date;
            _datePicker.MaximumDate = (NSDate) Element.Date.AddDays(1);
            _datePicker.MinimumDate = (NSDate) Element.Date.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(5));
            _datePicker.MinuteInterval = 1;

            SetNativeControl(_datePicker);
        }

        _datePicker.ValueChanged += DatePickerOnValueChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it work if you don't use a custom renderer? I don't have a physical devices with 13.3 now and I will test it later.

Comment: The default renderer for a Date View only handles dates OR times, and uses a text entry. Sadly did not meet my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by the extremely knowledgable ColeX over on the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/401506#Comment_401506). ColeX should really get the points for this, but I'm posting the answer here so that if anyone else searches for this issue on SO they will see a solution.

The root cause is dark mode on iOS when the app is not setup to render itself differently for light/dark mode. As a result the OS thinks it is rendering a date picker on a dark background, which it was not, and so it was effectively invisible. There are a [few solutions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26299#issuecomment-540261084) mentioned, but the one that worked for me was add the following to Info.plist in the iOS project:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Comment: OK, you can mark it later which can help more people with same problem:).